# Neo4j adding json as relationship, Invalid input '{':

Tags: json, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I'm using py2neo cypher to load relationship between nodes.  I would like to use a json object as this relationship, so I can query it later.  Here is my cypher query:

```
 MATCH (a:OntologyNode),(b:OntologyNode) 
 WHERE a.cid = 'abcat1' 
 AND b.cid = 'abcat2' 
 CREATE (a)-[r:{'operand2': 'Product_Weight', 'operand1': 'Maximum_Weight', 'operator': '>='}]->(b)
```

Here is my error:

```
 InvalidSyntax: Invalid input '{': expected whitespace or a rel type name (line 1, column 111 (offset: 110))
```

I appears it doesn't like the '{', but is there a way around this?  The reason I'd like this json as a relationship, is the ability to query it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the key/value pairs of the JSON as attributes on the relationship

```
MATCH (a:OntologyNode),(b:OntologyNode) 
WHERE a.cid = 'abcat1' 
AND b.cid = 'abcat2' 
CREATE (a)-[r:REL {operand2: 'Product_Weight', operand1: 'Maximum_Weight', operator: '>='}]->(b)
```

Then you could query it like this

```
MATCH (:OntologyNode)-[rel:REL]->(:OntologyNode) 
WHERE rel.operand2 = 'Product_Weight'
AND rel.operand1 = 'Maximum_Weight'
AND rel.operator = '>='
```

If you really wanted to use the actual JSON as the relationship then you could backtick the JSON string like this instead.

```
MATCH (a:OntologyNode),(b:OntologyNode) 
WHERE a.cid = 'abcat1' 
AND b.cid = 'abcat2' 
CREATE (a)-[r:`{operand2: 'Product_Weight', operand1: 'Maximum_Weight', operator: '>='}`]->(b)
```

If you wanted to combine the two, you could always store the JSON in another attribute on the relationship.

```
...
create (a)-[r:REL]->(b)
set r.operand2 = 'Product_Weight'
, r.operand1 = 'Maximum_Weight'
, r.operator = '>='
, r.json = "{operand2: 'Product_Weight', operand1: 'Maximum_Weight', operator: '>='}"
```

Comment: I really like the first approach.  From what I can tell, you just added the "REL" in from the json.  However, when I do that, I still get the error.

Comment: Yes, I added `REL` is the relationship type.  And I also unquoted the keys in the JSON: operand2, operand1 and operator.

Comment: The only issue with removing the quoting of keys is then it's not valid JSON.  Otherwise it would work great.  Any thoughts on how to fix that?

Comment: That is because the JSON in that example is the format that Neo4j cypher parser expects.  It consumes the JSON but actually stored the key/value pairs as attributes of the relationship object.  You could always add the raw JSON as an additional attribute on the relationship.  I updated the answer to include that as another option.

Comment: I still get the error when reading in using py2neo and json file.  One reason I can tell is it's always keeping the keys in quotes.  Using the set then json as an additional attribute also throws an error.

Comment: I only tested the cypher out in the browser; I have not tried it in py2neo.

Answer (score 0):

I am unclear what you mean by "I would like to use a json object as this relationship". A relationship is defined by Neo4j as a stored connection between two nodes with a textual type name and an optional map/dictionary of properties.

Please note also that JSON is merely a notation and not a type system. Furthermore, Cypher itself does not consume or produce JSON.

The literal map notation used by Cypher is *similar to* but not *compatible with* JSON. Property keys are generally unquoted except when they contain special characters, when backticks are used. Double quotes are not supported. Property keys should be considered *identifiers*, not strings.

You also say "the reason I'd like this json as a relationship, is the ability to query it". Cypher contains no JSON query functionality although you can of course query properties on a relationship.

If what you want is a relationship that contains properties, then you will need to give your relationship a type name and use Cypher map notation rather than JSON notation. Something like:

```
MATCH (a:OntologyNode),(b:OntologyNode) 
WHERE a.cid = 'abcat1' 
AND b.cid = 'abcat2' 
CREATE (a)-[r:RELATES_TO {operand2: 'Product_Weight', 
                          operand1: 'Maximum_Weight', operator: '>='}]->(b)
```

Obviously replace `RELATES_TO` with a relationship name appropriate for your domain.